# Only 1 row return in MySQL select query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why is it when i use the select query in MySQL database using PDO it only returns 1 row when in fact I need it all?

Here's my code

```
    $data= $connectionStrings->prepare("SELECT * FROM animals");
    $data->execute();
    $information = $data->fetch();
    return $information;
```

Comment: man you can just read this on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: Because you are asking it to only return one row. Fetch gets one row fetchall gets them all

Comment: @Darren haha i got them, anyway its in the manual with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using fetch() instead of fetchAll()

```
    $data= $connectionStrings->prepare("SELECT * FROM animals");
    $data->execute();
    $information = $data->fetchAll();
    return $information;
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
    $data= $connectionStrings->prepare("SELECT * FROM country");
    $data->execute();
    $information = $data->fetch();
    return $information;
```

If you want to return them all use `$data->fetchAll();` however, if you are returning a large results set it may cause your application to crash or be really slow.

By using `fetch()` in a loop you can handle the returned data one row at a time to ease the strain:

```
while ($row = $data->fetch()) {
 //handle $row
}
```

Comment: is this accurate? doing `->fetchAll()` vs `while($row = $data->fetch())`, `fetchAll` will be slower?

Comment: From my experience of handling large sets of data, `fetchAll()` will crash if you don't have a particularly high memory set for php so it's easier to loop through returned data one row at a time and handle it accordingly. I imagine `fetchAll()` would be quicker in general, not certain though

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php fetches all results. fetch() alone should be called many times. This is because result of query can be huge and it is not smart to load everything into memory at once. Depends on context of course.